# Getting external variable into metapost in ConTeXt

Tags: context, metapost

I'm new to ConTeXt and am trying to make a small theme for my presentations to get to know it better.

My slides have a title and a subtitle positioned in the header. I want to have random lines between the title and subtitle. The lines should join and become horizontal when passing directly between the title and subtitle.

I removed the irrelevant parts of my document. There is currently one line and it becomes flat near the centre for a length **w**. I'm trying to get the value of **w** from outside the MPpage.

To clarify a bit, here is what I currently get with the fixed value
(sorry, those are screenshots) :
[image: Too long]
[image: Correct]
[image: Too short]

Honestly, I don't even know where to begin to solve that. Any pointers are welcome. Below is a WE/MWE:

```
\setuppapersize[S6]

\setuplayout[headerdistance=1cm]

\definemarking[subtitle]
\starttexdefinition slidetitle
  \marking [subtitle] {\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
\stoptexdefinition

% Defining the slides
\definehead[slide] [subject][
    page=yes,
    placehead=empty,
    insidesection=\slidetitle,
]
%Putting the slide title and subtile in a table (to get 2 bloody lines) inside the header
\setupheadertexts [{%
    \bTABLE[frame=no,align=middle,offset=0.05cm]
        \bTR \bTD {\getmarking [slide]} \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD {\tfx\getmarking [subtitle]} \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLE
}]
\setupheader[text][style=\sc\ss\tfb]


\startuseMPgraphic {background}
StartPage;
    %Drawing the top lines. The variable w should be the max of the widths of the title and subtitle. So basically the width of the natural table containing them
    numeric w; path line;
    w=6cm;
    line:=((0,0) -- for i=1cm step 1cm until PaperWidth/2-w/2-1cm : (i,-uniformdeviate(0.7cm)) -- endfor (PaperWidth/2-w/2,-0.5cm) -- (PaperWidth/2+w/2,-0.5cm) -- for i=PaperWidth/2+w/2+1cm step 1cm until PaperWidth-1cm : (i,-uniformdeviate(0.7cm)) -- endfor (PaperWidth,0)) shifted (0,PaperHeight-1.8cm);
    drawpath line withpen pencircle scaled 1mm;
StopPage;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay [background][\reuseMPgraphic{background}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=background]


\starttext

\startslide[title={Hello}]
\input knuth
\stopslide

\startslide[title={Font examples}] [subtitle=a subtitle]
\input ward
\stopslide

\startslide[title={A very very long and detailed title}]
    [subtitle={As well as an inexcusably long and annoying subtitle}]
some text
\stopslide


\stoptext
```

Apologies if post doesn't respect some rule, not used to posting here.

Comment: I think you could use positionnal graphics, as defined in Metafun manual chapter 5.

Comment: Your MWE does not give the output of your screenshots. I edited it to have the third one printed, but you should either add your background elements or better sent screenshots that you get when compiling your MWE.

Comment: Oh, and btw, welcome to TeX S.E.!

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I was looking for, guess I should read the manuals a bit more closely next time. Thank you very much!
For the MWE, my bad, I stripped the document but forgot about it when making the screenshots :/
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by sztruks:

> I think you could use positional graphics, as defined in Metafun manual chapter 5.

EDIT:
What I get using positional graphics is not exactly right. 
I assign an \hpos to the title-subtitle bundle and get its width. Unfortunately, as far as I understand, \startMPpositiongraphic is only calculated after the whole document has been typeset, at which point the \hpos only refers to the title-subtitle of the very last page. As a result, the lines are not drawn on all but the last page. There however they are drawn with the right dimensions.

EDIT2: Solved by simply putting value of counter in hpos (specifically \userpagenumber) as well as putting the \start/stoppositionoverlay code inside some function executed at each slide (so that the counter gets updated, otherwise only the first page gets a drawing). 
Not posting new pictures since the one below already describes what I get.

Marking the question as answered.

Here is what I now have:

```
\setuppapersize[S6]

\setuplayout[headerdistance=1cm]

\definemarking[subtitle]
\starttexdefinition slidetitle
    \marking [subtitle] {\structureuservariable{subtitle}}
    \startpositionoverlay{posover:background}
        \setMPpositiongraphic{titles-\userpagenumber}{background}{self=titles-\userpagenumber}
    \stoppositionoverlay
\stoptexdefinition

% Defining the slides
\definehead[slide] [subject][
    page=yes,
    placehead=empty,
    insidesection=\slidetitle,
]
%Putting the slide title and subtile in a table (to get 2 bloody lines) inside the header
\setupheadertexts [\hpos{titles-\userpagenumber}{%
    \bTABLE[frame=no,align=middle,offset=0.05cm]
        \bTR \bTD {\getmarking [slide]} \eTD \eTR
        \bTR \bTD {\tfx\getmarking [subtitle]} \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLE
}]
\setupheader[text][style=\sc\ss\tfb]


\startMPpositiongraphic {background}
StartPage;
    %Drawing the top lines. The variable w should be the max of the widths of the title and subtitle. So basically the width of the natural table containing them
    numeric w; path line;
    w=\MPw{\MPvar{self}} ;
    line:=((0,0) -- for i=1cm step 1cm until PaperWidth/2-w/2-1cm : (i,-uniformdeviate(0.7cm)) -- endfor (PaperWidth/2-w/2,-0.5cm) -- (PaperWidth/2+w/2,-0.5cm) -- for i=PaperWidth/2+w/2+1cm step 1cm until PaperWidth-1cm : (i,-uniformdeviate(0.7cm)) -- endfor (PaperWidth,0)) shifted (0,PaperHeight-1.8cm);
    drawpath line withpen pencircle scaled 1mm;
StopPage;
\stopMPpositiongraphic


\defineoverlay [over:background][\positionoverlay{posover:background}]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=over:background]


\starttext

\startslide[title={Hello}]
\input knuth
\stopslide

\startslide[title={Font examples}] [subtitle=a subtitle]
\input ward
\stopslide

\startslide[title={A very very long and detailed title}]
    [subtitle={As well as an inexcusably long and annoying subtitle}]
some text
\stopslide


\stoptext
```

The result is this for the last page:
[image: You can notice the lines and titles are not exactly vertically aligned. It's not the case in the complete example. Too]
You can notice the lines and titles are not exactly vertically aligned. It's not the case in the complete example. Too tired to figure out why.

Comment: I did not really answer: the trouble is I'm not able to put this chapter into practice, because I’m not used to overlays yet. So I am looking forward to seeing how you solved the problem…

Comment: I am currently not on my computer so I can only read the chapter. I'll try to implement a solution tonight. But the chapter was exactly the link between content and position I was looking for, so I'm hopeful.